# How to select element from drop-down menu via selenium and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to play with autologin tests via selenium driver and python.
I am using this site https://invoiceaccess.pgiconnect.com/
What i did:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("https://invoiceaccess.pgiconnect.com")
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginId").send_keys("test-account")
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginPassword").send_keys("test-password")
    #driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```

Everythyhing works, but i have a problem with selecting from drop-down menu. For example, i have html code of this menu.

```
    <select class="regiondropdown" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please Select Region" id="Region" name="Region"><option value="">Select Region</option>
    <option value="us">America</option>
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="apac">APAC</option>
    </select>
```

I tried this:

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Region']")
    all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in all_options:
        print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("US"))
        option.click()
```

For example, i need to select `America`, but it selects `APAC`. Where i made error, who can help me please ?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the inner text of each option ? Or specifically the option which has "us" for value ?

Comment: @mgc i want to select `US`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the specific option of your `select` element which has `us` for value you can use the [`Select`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html) selenium class to do something like this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

option = Select(
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Region']")
).select_by_value("us")
print(option.text) # Should print 'America'
```

Or you can also do this with css selectors :

```
selec = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Region']")
option = selec.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value=\"us\"]")
print(option.text) # Should print 'America'
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the value America from drop down box try this code.It worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome("Path of the Chrome driver" + "chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get("https://invoiceaccess.pgiconnect.com")

select =Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Region"))
select.select_by_value("us")
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic code for list using xpath and select

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://invoiceaccess.pgiconnect.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
def ListItemSelection(countrycode):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='" + countrycode + "']").click()

ListItemSelection("us")
time.sleep(1)
ListItemSelection("europe")
time.sleep(1)
ListItemSelection("apac")
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```