# Selenium not clicking on given element but click on next element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to select a value from the dropdown menu and I am also able to select a value but it will select another value, not which that I have given.

Please see the below video. when I click on the dropdown one class appears in the background. and using that class I have created XPath but it will select a different value.

https://www.loom.com/share/e60dd141c3da426080646ec527cc029f

I have used this XPath for clicking on the dropdown and selecting values from it.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shipping_address"]//*[@class="Select-arrow"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//*[text()="Alaska"]').click()
```

I have many tried but not successes can anyone can help me?

Comment: Looks like the locator you are using is not unique. Can you share a link to that web page?

Comment: @Prophet this private so I can not share the link. but I am dam sure the locators are 100% unique.

Comment: Can you please check that the locators are unique?

Comment: @Prophet Please see the screenshots https://ibb.co/r5tzWmq

Comment: I see. And you are clicking on this element, but another element is selected?

Comment: @Prophet Yes, it will select "Arizona" instead of "Alaska".

Comment: That's very strange..  can you try some other state name and see what happens? Will it still select the next element in the list?
BTW, can you please share your code block where you opening the drop list and selecting the option there?

Comment: Please paste this inside the question to make it readable

Comment: @Prophet Question edited

Comment: I see.. Really looks correct. I'm sorry, currently have no idea what's wrong here. Need to debug that.

Comment: @Prophet I will send you full code and web access can you helpme more?

Comment: I would do this with a pleasure, but I have no selenium with python on my PC at all these days... I'm sorry

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the relevant html? And what happens if you select Californië (as @prophet asked). Wild guess, does using the Select class help you? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100588/how-to-select-element-from-drop-down-menu-via-selenium-and-python

Comment: @TacoVerhagen Please check the screenshots if you got any idea. https://ibb.co/2FWshd2

Answer (score -1):

The problem: you are clicking the div which contains ALL states instead of the specific state you want. To be exact you click the div[@class="Select-menu"]. What you want is this (1 layer deeper):

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="shipping_address"]//*[@class="Select-arrow"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//div[@role="option" and text()="Alaska"]').click()
```

General hint, if the FIRST item is always selected than you are clicking 1 level to 'low' in the tree.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it is not working.